# Lighten/darken color depending on background

Tags: visual-studio-code

Given a color customization in my `settings.json`, how can I lighten a color value when I load a dark theme?

I believe I'm looking after some sort of CSS functionality that would let me do something along the lines of (pseudocode)

```
"foreground": mix(20%, inverse(background-color), "#861000")
```

Comment: The closest you are going to get, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme with your themes like so: `"[Monokai]"` as the link shows.  And then you change themes manually when you want - nothing as dynamic as you are thinking about.

Comment: That's really sad! I was able to do this in Atom. :(